# Combo Box pop up and select using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, key-bindings

```
   public static void comboBoxActionPerform(JComboBox  comboBox)
    {
        String ACTION_KEY = "myAction";

        Action actionListener = new AbstractAction()
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
            {
                JComboBox source = (JComboBox) actionEvent.getSource();
                source.showPopup();
                source.setFocusable(true);
            }
        };

        KeyStroke ctrlT = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_L, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
        InputMap inputMap = comboBox.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(ctrlT, ACTION_KEY);
        ActionMap actionMap = comboBox.getActionMap();
        actionMap.put(ACTION_KEY, actionListener);
        locationTypeComboBox.setActionMap(actionMap);
    }
```

I have a com box and I call the above method to pop up combo box on keys (Ctrl+L) pressed.
It pops up the combo box. But I can't select the items in it using UP/DOWN keys.
Combo box get not focused when I pressed Ctrl+L. That might be the issue to be fixed.
If I select the combo box manually and then up/down works fine. Need your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you are looking for is requestFocus, not setFocusable

```
    Action actionListener = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            JComboBox source = (JComboBox) actionEvent.getSource();
            source.requestFocus();
            source.showPopup();
            // source.setFocusable(true);
        }
    };
```

BTW, it's unusual to reset the actionMap of a component.

Comment: not it doesn't works in Java6 on WinXP, on 1.st key_down or key_up, 2nd works

Comment: worksforme (jdk7, win7 - but that shouldn't make much of a difference) - try to wrap the showPopup in an invokeLater.

Comment: agree +1 for sterille solution with one fucusable JCOmponent, then works, but lostFocus in the case that there are fosusable JComponents, just for fun to try to change WHEN_FOCUSED to WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, then only 1.st JComboBox react to KeyEvents :-), strangeeeee, funny and crazy for most complex GUI