# JavaFX ComboBox: Quick-selection with letter keys

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-8

Is it possible to quick-select the first/next entry by typing the letter this entry starts with?

EXAMPLE: Given following combobox entries:

- Green
- Blue
- Red
- Pink

Setting focus on the combbox and typing `B` shout select "Blue".

Comment: Look at the accepted solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363990/combo-box-pop-up-and-select-using-keyboard-shortcuts and comment out source.showPopup(). It seems twork.

Comment: @edwin But that is about Swing and not about JavaFX.